# What percentage of scientific articles and thesis are made with LaTeX?

Tags: latex-misc

Are there any statistics about what proportion of published articles/papers and thesis are made with LaTeX or any TeX variant?

It would specially interesting to see statiscs by subjects (math, physics, statistics, computer science, engineering, biology, medicine... or even language, history, psychology)

Comment: A very optimistic  percentage:  29%.   Google: Submission  guidelines LaTeX:  16.200.000  results. Submission  guidelines Word:  55.200.000 results.

Comment: @Fran: That depends on the domain. In maths, it's 100%, and probably nearly as much in statistics, physics and computer science. Second, there's abias: what is the proportion of submission guidelines for Word **and** LaTeX? Some journals may accept both.

Comment: @Bernard Of course that there are a strong  bias in the search and depend of the science field.   You know: lies, damned lies  ... and statistics.  That's why I said "very optimistic" and you pointed  the nearly 100% in some fields. I'll sit and watch for something minimally grounded about this issue.

Comment: I only know that yesterday I fought all day with a Word document that did not want to format as I wanted. Why can't I use LaTeX at work? : '( However, the question is very interesting! I hope someone can answer!

Comment: @Fran How do you get those figures?. Anyway this is only for "submission guidelines". In many places you can send articles in any format or in pdf (converted from any source, LaTeX, Word, other) and I don't know if there is a way to know the original format.

Comment: I guess the best way to know it would be surveying the writters.

Comment: @skan (a)It's a simple Google search. (b) Not the best way, just the only way, but I'm afraid that still nobody walked seriously in that way. But if you want another general hint: https://www.google.es/trends/explore?date=all&q=%2Fm%2F052yv,%2Fm%2F04mdr